# Approximating by independent Poisson random variables

Tags: pr.probability, limit-theorems

Using the Chen-Stein method, one can bound the total variation distance between a sum of possibly dependent Bernoulli random variables $W=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ and a Poisson distribution using only the first and second moments of the $X_i$. For example, see [Two Moments Suffice for Poisson Approximations, by Arratia et al.](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aop/1176991491).

Is there an analogous bound for the total variation distance in the multivariate case? For example, if
\begin{equation*}
W_1 : = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i, \ \ \ 
W_2 : = \sum_{j=1}^n Y_j.
\end{equation*}
are sums of (not necessarily independent) Bernoulli random variables, then can we bound  $d_{TV}(\mathcal{L}(W_1, W_2), \mathcal{L}( Poi(E[W_1]), Poi(E[W_2]))$, using the first and second moments of $X_i$ and $Y_j$ (these poisson random variables are independent)$? In the literature, I've only found bounds for the case where these Bernoulli random variables are presumed to be independent.

EDIT: Whoops. I should have read through the paper that I cited. See Theorem 2 in Arratia et al.

Comment: What is $\mathcal{L}$?

Comment: By $\mathcal{L}$, I mean the law (distribution) of these random variables.

Comment: If $W_1, W_2$ are dependent, it seems unreasonable for the law of $(W_1, W_2)$ to be well approximated by a pair of independent Poissons.  For example, what happens if $X_i = Y_i$ so that $W_1 = W_2$?

Comment: In that case, the second (mixed) moments would hopefully be too large and give an upper bound on the total variation distance that would be meaningless. For example, in the 1-dimensional case, if there is too much dependence between the $X_i$'s, the $b_2 = \sum_{\alpha} \sum_{\beta \in N_{\alpha}} E[X_{\alpha} X_{\beta}]$ term would be large (here $N_\alpha$ can be thought of as the dependence neighborhood of $X_\alpha$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is "yes".

Longer answer: it is enough to show that
the variable
$Z:= W_1+ W_2$ converges to Poisson with the correct parameter. Now apply the "Two moments suffice". Note that if the $W_1$ and $W_2$ are dependent,
the conditions of the latter may fail - but at least they can be checked using first and second (including cross) moments.

Added in edit: In case that the dependence between the X and Y variables is strong, the
limiting Poisson variables may be correlated, and the 
limit of $W_1+W_2$ might be compound Poisson instead of Poisson (this would be the case for example if $X_i=Y_i$). For the local method for  compound Poisson approximation, see e.g. http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoap/1177004910

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. I am having trouble seeing why $W_1$ and $W_2$ would be forced to be asymptotically independent in this case rather than simply asymptotically uncorrelated.